# getElementById Not Working Right

Tags: javascript

Ok, so I'm REALLY new to programming and javascript, but I'm having a problem with this little string of code. The thing that is bothering me about it, is that I have done things similar to this in other programs, but it's just not working right in this specific little part of this program. Here is basically what isn't working:

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript">

function test()
{
var myTextField = document.getElementById('myText');
document.write (myTextField);
}

</script>


<form>
<input type="text" id="myText">
<input type="submit" value="submit" OnClick="test()">
</form>
</html>
```

When I do this, it returns [object HTMLInputElement] instead of the value of that text field. Thanks for any help cause I'm most of you know this. :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getElementById returns the Object itself, which has many methods and properties as members.

You need to reference the `value` property, like this:

`document.getElementById('myText').value;`

That should work :)

Also, here's a general reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/A_re-introduction_to_JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
document.write (myTextField.value);
```

Comment: getElementById() returns the actual element - in this case a textbox. Use .value to get the text within the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
function test()
{
var myTextField = document.getElementById('myText').value;
alert(myTextField);
// or 
console.log(myTextField);
}
```

You should not use document.write here, as you document is already loaded. Document.write will remove the page.

Comment: I understand, I don't normally use document.write except tests. Although ya, an alert would still be better.

Comment: @JackstahComradDavis an alert is better than doc write, but installing firebug and using console.log would be even better.